# How to access inner controls through styleManager?

Tags: flex4, flex4.5

I'd like to know if there is a way to access inner controls of the spark control (lets say Panel) through the styleManager?

I've used the following code to access Panel's CSS properties:

```
styleManager.getStyleDeclaration("spark.components.Panel")
            .setStyle("backgroundColor", "blue");
```

I'm unable to figure out how to access the inner controls like displayLabel. I know that this is possible using the CSS styling, but I'd like to change their properties at runtime.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is still current, but I think what you need to do is to declare the inner classes somehow in your CSS (possibly empty if you don't care). As soon as they exist there, the styleManager can access their values. You can also do something like this:

```
[Style(name="backgroundColor", type="uint", format="Color")]
```

In your MXML declaration, and then that style exists.

There are a few related examples here:
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf687e7-7ff6.html

[This is related to an issue I have myself with the StyleManager and google led me here, that's the reason for the late answer]